# JSEvaluateScript does not execute js files with multiple lines

Tags: javascriptcore

I'm using javascriptcore to execute some js code in c++.

OS: windows 8

IDE: visual studio 2013

Content in js file:

```
log('a');
log('b');
```

I found the method

```
JSEvaluateScript(ctx, script, NULL, NULL, 1, &exception);
```

does not work as expected, so I checked the syntax before it:

```
JSCheckScriptSyntax(ctx, script, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Then got the error:

```
ASSERTION FAILED: !source.provider()->source().isNull()
C:\jsctest\webkit\Source\JavaScriptCore\parser\Parser.h(1081): JSC::parse 
First-chance exception at 0x013A1E77 in JavaScriptCoreTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xBBADBEEF. 
Unhandled exception at 0x013A1E77 in JavaScriptCoreTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xBBADBEEF.
```

Answer (score 1):

After some tests, I found that:

If I put them in 2 lines, it does not work.

If I put them in the same line, it works.

If I convert the file with cmd `dos2unix`, it works.

so it seems that javascriptcore does not support `\r\n` in js files.